# Is "tribuo" derrived from "tribus" or vice versa?

Tags: etymology

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tribuo#Latin), the verb *tribuo* comes from *tribus*. But further search led me to [this etymological dictionary](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=JbFWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA483&lpg=PA483&dq=latin%20etymology%20tribuo&source=bl&ots=0V0DvRD7zb&sig=ACfU3U0frdb3La6xW5jaTCm46pVOo3wCPA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj20b-GrKrqAhWFUcAKHU6tCM4Q6AEwB3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=latin%20etymology%20tribuo&f=false), which in turn cites Forcelleni on those two entries; On *tribuo* Forcelleni writes it is from *triubus*, however, as observed by the referred dictionary, Forcelleni has "circular argument" since on *tribus* he says it might come from *tribuo* ("... or because the tribes paid tribute").

But this dictionary is now almost 200 years old, I wonder whether this issue was settled down in our days? or at least have more probable conjecture.

Comment: I never heared of the dictionary, is THIS an abbreviation perhaps? Please give the title, linkrot is a ting you kno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De Vaan's *Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the other Italic Languages* traces *tribus* to Proto-Indo-European **tri-dʰh₁-u-* 'tripartite division' > Proto-Italic **triþu-* 'tripartite entity, trinity', and lists *tribuere* as a derivation, along with *tribūnus* and *tribūtus* and a few more obvious ones. He doesn't say it, but PIE **tri-* is the zero-grade form of **tréyes* 'three', and **dʰh₁-* is the zero-grade of the verbal root **dʰeh₁-* 'to do, put, place'. Compare also Sanskrit *trídhā* 'threefold', from the e-grade of that root.

He also doesn't spell out why a word meaning "tripartite" should come to mean "tribe", but it's presumably because the Roman people were traditionally divided into three tribes: the Ramnes/Ramnenses, Tities/Titienses, and Luceres/Lucerenses, usually taken as corresponding to the city's Latin, Sabine, and Etruscan populations, respectively. (Why the Umbrian cognate *trifu* then also meant tribe/people, though, needs explanation.)

Comment: Tities :D The problem with the tri-partite div. is that it has all the hallmarks of a folk ety. Describing folks, it is literally a folk etymology. Might be why DeVaan left it out, besides it being well known in any event